# Trigger in Task Scheduler with ending Application (Exe-Path is variable)

Tags: powershell, xml

<sup>(Please excuse my bad English)</sup> 
 I'm using Task Scheduler to trigger a restart of a program that is running as a shell (for a Kiosk mode with this program). I can only use Win10 Pro, which can't handle Shell-Events by itself, so I need the Task Scheduler (only Win10 Enterprise supports that).

This works fine, but the path of the program changes after updates; the `.exe` name stays the same, but the `.exe` is in another cryptic directory:

```xml
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and Task = 13313 and (band(Keywords,9007199254740992)) and (EventID=4689)]] and *[EventData[(Data='Exe-Path')]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

- Is it possible to check for the Process Name, instead of via the `.exe` path, as I can't find anything?
- How do I get the command "match" working, as I could then look for the `.exe` name inside the path-string; I can't find any example of this if it's possible?

Comment: Have you tried using regex or other variables to match the `.exe` to its new directory? Another approach could be to run a Task every time the program is updated _(started via a custom Event that's monitoring for the change)_ to rename its directory to a sane naming scheme _(kill the program via a task monitoring for the event, a new task to run based on the first that renames the program, then a final task monitoring the second to restart the program - this is what I do to backup Outlook databases daily since Outlook can't be running for the backup to occur)_

Comment: Thx for the answer! I looked for regex, but don't know how to use. I found no examples, just that in xml its only for inputs. Also the regex editors i found dont support xml, so not sure about the correct syntax.

How is the syntax in general? Tried around an nothing worked.

I cant rename the directory unfortunatelly.

Alternatively: How do i use negotiation in the query? Is it possible to use: not ?
Then i could check if the app is running via batchfile after trigger via task scheduler.

Running that batch every minute isnt possible, too.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with regex and always have to look up how to use it _(it would be specified in the task via the parameters of a program that supports it)_, however a simpler approach to my previous comment may be a symlink since the directory can't be renamed: a task to monitor for when the `.exe` is updated, a task to remove the symlink if it exists, and a final task running with Admin privs to symlink the `.exe` to a sane name: `MkLink "C:\Program\Path\sane-name.exe" "C:\Program\Path\original-name.exe"`

Comment: _Cont'd..._ Tasks 1 & 2 will need to be monitored by separate custom events in Event Viewer, as Tasks 2 & 3 will be triggered by the previous event: Task 1 runs → Task 2 is triggered by the event monitoring for Task 1's completion → Task 3 is triggered by event monitoring for Task 2's completion _([example](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/Outlook) of a monitoring event's XML Properties and it's accompanied task)_ I don't have the time at the moment to create an answer with all the steps, but will when I have time.